# iOS Push Notification not work on odd device

Tags: ios, push-notification

Testing the Push Notifications on my iOS App, these are the results:

- iPhone SE (iOS 12) works OK. (Development and Production)
- iPhone 5 (iOS 10) is also good.
- iPhone 8 (iOS 11). OK on Development but it is not working on Production.
  None of the notifications is shown, even silent notifications are not working when the app is installed from App Sotre or TestFlight, but from XCode, with the same Device with the same app version are still working in Debug.

I am using UNUserNotificationCenter, are there any restriction for iOS 11 on Production? What can I have forgotten?

Comment: Can you show the notification payload that you are sending from the server?

Comment: That is the notification: {
  "title": "Test title",
  "text": "Test message",
  "keyname": ""
}